# Cox regression HR grouping

Tags: r, cox-regression

I would like to perform a Cox regression for the following questions: A group of patients receives a treatment "drug" or not (0 / 1). My time variable "time" tells me, how many days the patient is observed and "status" if the patient survived or died (died = 1, survived = 0).

```
library(survival)

set.seed(123)

df <- data.frame(time = round(runif(100, min = 1, max = 70)), 
                 status = round(runif(100, min = 0, max = 1)),
                 drug = round(runif(100, min = 0, max = 1)),
                 age40 = round(runif(100, min = 0, max = 1)), 
                 stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

object <- Surv(df$time, df$status)
model <- coxph(object ~ drug, data = df)
summary(model)
```

This works fine for me and tells me, that the HR is 0.89, so the drug prevents patients from dying.

Now I want to do some **subgroup analysis**, f.e. how does the HR change, if the patient is <= 40 years or > 40 years old (age40: 0 vs 1).

Is all I have to do to include the variable "age40" into the coxph?

```
object2 <- Surv(df$time, df$status)
model2 <- coxph(object2 ~ drug + age40, data = df)
summary(model2)
```

If I do that my HR in the summary for drug1 slightly changes to 0.86 and I get another one for age40 (1.12).

Now my question is: How are the Hazard Ratios for dying under treatment (drug = 1) if the patient is <= 40 or > 40 years old.

**EDIT: Another question would be to graphically show the different HRs of the effect of drug on status in a forest plot**, f.e. like this: https://rpkgs.datanovia.com/survminer/reference/ggforest-2.png.
Instead of "sex", "rx", "adhere" etc. I would like to show the HRs for Age40 = 0 vs. 1 and other variables as well, like hypertension = 0 vs. 1, smoker = 0 vs. 1.

Thank you!

Comment: "Cox" is a person's name. You should not be spelling it with all caps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function you need to use is `predict` on your `model2`, and it needs to be supplied with a newdata argument that includes all the cases that you want to consider:

```
exp( predict(model2, newdata=expand.grid(drug=c(0,1), age40=c(0,1))) )
#        1         2         3         4 
#1.0000000 0.8564951 1.1268713 0.9651598
```

You now have all 4 cases of possible combinations of drug and age40. The base case has a value of unity because you are estimating risk ratios form a baseline case of {drug=0, age40=0} You can see what the other risk ratios are associated with

```
expand.grid(drug=c(0,1), age40=c(0,1))
  drug age40
1    0     0
2    1     0
3    0     1
4    1     1
```

Notice that the ratio of drug=0 to drug=1 is the same for each age category considered separately. If you had wanted to see if the effects of drug was different in the two age categories you would have used an interaction model:

```
model3 <- coxph(object2 ~ drug * age40, data = df)
summary(model3)
#----------------
Call:
coxph(formula = object2 ~ drug * age40, data = df)

  n= 100, number of events= 50 

               coef exp(coef) se(coef)      z Pr(>|z|)
drug       -0.18524   0.83091  0.45415 -0.408    0.683
age40       0.09611   1.10089  0.39560  0.243    0.808
drug:age40  0.05679   1.05843  0.63094  0.090    0.928

           exp(coef) exp(-coef) lower .95 upper .95
drug          0.8309     1.2035    0.3412     2.024
age40         1.1009     0.9084    0.5070     2.390
drug:age40    1.0584     0.9448    0.3073     3.645

Concordance= 0.528  (se = 0.042 )
Likelihood ratio test= 0.34  on 3 df,   p=1
Wald test            = 0.33  on 3 df,   p=1
Score (logrank) test = 0.33  on 3 df,   p=1
```

And the effect estimates are now a bit different:

```
 exp( predict(model3, newdata=expand.grid(drug=c(0,1), age40=c(0,1))) )
#        1         2         3         4 
#1.0000000 0.8309089 1.1008850 0.9681861
```

Comment: Hi IRTFM! Thank you so much for your comprehensive answer - this seems to be a good solution for me. Now I had another question on graphical presentation of the HRs you calculated. I edited my quesion in the end with "EDIT: Another question would be to graphically show the different HR in a forest plot". Could you maybe help me on that as well? Thank you!!

Comment: I’m guessing you want a display like that produced by packages that deliver what many people now (incorrectly) call “forest plots”. A correctly produced forest plot only displays a single type of effect measure from multiple studies in an effort to assess publication bias. I think the correct term is ladder plot, but I’m not sure. In any case it’s a new question if you are not able to find any of the several already asked and answered questions on SO and the Web.

Answer (score 0):

Use argument `strata`.

```
coxph(object ~ drug + strata(age40), data = df)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. I added the "strata(age40)" argument, but in the summary(model) there is no differentiation between age40 = 0 and age40 = 1 or something like that. Just the HR for drug changed from 0.8887 to 0.8917. Do I interpret this new HR on condition that drug = 1 AND age40 = 1?

Comment: @MDStat Did you try summary of that model? If so try set `age40` as factor.

Comment: Yes, I used the summary. Both I changed age40 to a factor in the data frame as well as in the coxph function - no effect. Could you maybe post your code that works for you? Sorry for additional questions...

Comment: I don't think that is what is being asked. Using `strata` creates a pooled estimate for the age40 variable, whereas what was asked was for some method to examine differences in effects across ages